# Why do "data Unit = Unit" and "()" behave differently in GHCi?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, evaluation

In GHCi: (> means output)

```hs
data Unit = Unit
let x = Unit
let y = ()
:p x
> x = (_t1::Unit)
:p y
> y = ()
:i ()
> data () = ()    -- Defined in `GHC.Tuple'
```

Why do `Unit` and `()` behave differently? There are also other types that behave like `()`, for example `Int` and `Char`. Are there any other such types?

Surprisingly, when I replace `()` by `undefined`, it behaves as I expected again:

```hs
let y = undefined :: ()
:p y
y = (_t2::())
```

Comment: I don't fully understand this difference either, but it seems to have to do with the code being compiled or not. For example `let x = True` and `:p x` also shows `x = True`. And compiling the module with the `Unit` definition makes it match the behaviour of `()`.

Comment: I have an idea. The `Unit` constructor is like a top level constant. If it is evaluated once, it stays evaluated for the whole run time of the program. I guess some values are `evaluated` (because almost every program needs them) by default. You can test this when you try `let x = Unit; y = Unit`. Even if you only evaluate `y`, x will be evaluated too after.

Comment: @bennofs If you make the type `newtype Unit = Unit ()`, or `data Unit = Unit ()`, you also get different behavior, they behave more like `()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to look at this GHCi session:

```
Prelude> data Unit = Unit deriving Show
Prelude> let x = Unit
Prelude> let x2 = Unit
Prelude> :p x
x = (_t1::Unit)
Prelude> x2
Unit
Prelude> :p x
x = <.:Interactive.Unit>
Prelude> let x3 = Unit
Prelude> :p x3
x3 = <.:Interactive.Unit>
```

Basically, after `x` and `x2` are defined, `x` is an unevaluated thunk. After I force the evaluation of `x2`, we discover that `x` was evaluated as well. Variable `x3`, despite being defined later, is never in an unevaluated state.

I believe that GHCi is playing some optimization here, creating just a single thunk for `Unit`. Every time you use the value constructor `Unit`, GHCi re-uses that thunk. Hence, the first time the single thunk is forced, every variable defined through the constructor appears in an evaluated state.

IIRC, small `Integer` literals use a shared pre-evaluated thunk as well:

```
Prelude> let y3 = 3 :: Integer
Prelude> :p y3
y3 = 3
Prelude> let y4 = 344444444444444 :: Integer
Prelude> :p y4
y4 = (_t3::Integer)
```